# Predicate in Map or Reduce (RavenDb)?

Tags: ravendb

If I want to apply a predicate to a document before I aggregate in a Reduce function, do I want to place that predicate in the Map function, or in the Reduce function?

So for example putting the predicate in the Map function would look like this:

```
        Map = orders => orders
            .Where(order => order.Status != OrderStatus.Cancelled)
            .Select(order => new
                {
                    Name = order.Firstname + ' ' + order.Lastname,
                    TotalSpent = order.Total,
                    NumberOfOrders = 1
                });
        Reduce = results => results
            .GroupBy(result => result.Email)
            .Select(customer => new
                {
                    Name = customer.Select(c => c.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                    TotalSpent = customer.Sum(c => c.TotalSpent),
                    NumberOfOrders = customer.Sum(c => c.NumberOfOrders)
                });
```

And putting it in the Reduce function would look like this:

```
        Map = orders => orders
            .Select(order => new
                {
                    Name = order.Firstname + ' ' + order.Lastname,
                    TotalSpent = order.Total,
                    NumberOfOrders = 1,
                    Status = order.Status
                });
        Reduce = results => results
            .Where(order => order.Status != OrderStatus.Cancelled)
            .GroupBy(result => result.Email)
            .Select(customer => new
                {
                    Name = customer.Select(c => c.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                    TotalSpent = customer.Sum(c => c.TotalSpent),
                    NumberOfOrders = customer.Sum(c => c.NumberOfOrders),
                    Status = (OrderStatus)0
                });
```

The latter obviously makes more sense, however it means that I have to add the Status property to the class of the Reduce result and then just set it to some unknown value in the Reduce as it doesn't actually mean anything there.

Comment: On the same note, does having an OrderBy in the Map function actually do anything? For example, if I want to use FirstOrDefault() in the Reduce function based on a specific ordering that I've introduced in the Map function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the first approach works for map/reduce. And no, the order will be ignored and you can't do something like FirstOrDefault in the result.

You need to think of map/reduce as two independent functions whereas the reduce function can be run multiple times on the same input, that's why the format of the input must match the format of the output. This can also happen on different server in parallel and asynchronously, thus new documents can be saved while the indexing is running.

Comment: So you are actually 'reducing' (with a predicate) in your Map function. Slightly counter-intuitive but oh well! You can use FirstOrDefault in your Reduce, but what you are saying is that there is no way to try and get the first item based on any order? What if you do it actually in the aggregation (inside the Select)?

Comment: Alex, I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean. I need some code to give an answer.